# JSF Datatable data gone when I click(select) row mutiple times

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My jsf code like this

```
<p:dataTable var="item"  rowKey="#{item.brId}" value="#{bidsWinAction.resultsModel}" emptyMessage="#{msgs.comm_no_record}"  selectionMode="single"  id="data" >
```

It is binding to a @ViewScoped bean:

```
public class BidsWinAction implements Serializable {
     public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
          this.selectedItems = (BidsResult)event.getObject();
      }
```

I works when you click ant row in the table, it can get correct selected data in the methods  onRowSelect.

But when I keep clicking different rows in the table at many times, all data became null including datatable. I guess is it possible  ViewScoped bean is expired. why cause this issues?

Comment: Check what's going on with the backing bean. Is it creating once and again every time you click a row?

Comment: please include more code because with what you are showing it's not possible to determine the problem. where do you declare the call to onRowSelect? where are you showing selected data and how?